# Why does ajax.php script duplicate in wordpress header

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have this `add_action` to load my ajax var in the header of wordpress, but for some reason it duplicates the call. I have another method setup too and no matter what it will duplicate the var for ajax. I know you can run the php call in the ajax script to avoid using this method but I want to keep my js in a js file and not place it in the footer or header.

```
add_action('wp_head', array($this, 'my_fts_ajaxurl'));

function my_fts_ajaxurl() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myAjaxFTS = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

and this is what gets returned in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var myAjaxFTS='http://www.example.net/betablog/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';</script>
<script type="text/javascript">var myAjaxFTS='http://www.example.net/betablog/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';</script>
```

I also have another method in place that uses the wordpress method. I'm using a class.

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'fts_clear_cache_script'));
add_action('wp_ajax_fts_clear_cache_ajax', array($this, 'fts_clear_cache_ajax'));

function fts_clear_cache_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('fts_clear_cache_script', plugins_url('feed-them-social/admin/js/developer-admin.js'), array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('fts_clear_cache_script', 'ftsAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    wp_enqueue_script('fts_clear_cache_script');
}
```

And this is what gets returned in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var ftsAjax = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/www.example.net\/betablog\/wp-
admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
var ftsAjax = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/www.example.net\/betablog\/wp-
admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: You should look into Enqueueing scripts instead of printing them out into wp_head.  Or, take a look at this to see how to check if the script has been added once already: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33674/anonymous-function-is-executed-twice-in-wp-head-while-added-from-the-posts-filte

Comment: The other method I mentioned was an enqueuing method too and the same result happened but this check might be exactly what I need. Looking now thanks for the link.

Comment: i usually consider this a little unsafe, you should take in account that this javascript call url can be edited in browser by user in the page code, leading to an ajax call done to whatever url he chooses. Maybe you should use what wordpress offers you for ajax calls, with an action like `add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');`

Comment: @Kaddath I have that method in place too and it does the same thing except it only duplicated the var within the script element, so in both cases I'm still getting a duplicate of the var.

Comment: @SlickRemix i was just assuming that you expose the ajax url to perform ajax calls with it, and saying that these later ajax calls should be done by wordpress instead of your own js. But if you need it in the header for another reason, the first comment may be what you want..

Comment: updated answer to show wp method too.